# Error: Demasiados argumentos

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Necesito comparar todas las palabras que las paso como argumentos entre si, y decir si son iguales o no:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Ejercicio_4
if [ $# -ne 6 ]
  then
        echo Número de argumentos incorrecto
  else
        if [ $1 == $2 == $3 == $4 == $5 == $6 ]

                then
                        echo Son iguales
                else
                        echo No todas las palabras son iguales
        fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, tu sentencia `if` no es válida, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
if [[ $1 == $2 && $1 == $3 && $1 == $4 && $1 == $5 && $1 == $6 ]];
```

Básicamente:

- Comparamos cada parámetro con el primero mediante `and` lógico (`&&`), si todos son verdaderos entonces todos son iguales.
- Toma nota que usamos `[[` en vez de  `[`, los dobles corchetes son una mejora de Bash al corchete simple, que entre otras cosas permite usar operadores lógicos.

Comment: Gracias me solucionaste justo lo que pedia

Answer (score 0):

El error de "Demasiados argumentos" es porque el operador `[` (sinónimo del otro built-in de bash `test`) es un operador binario o unario, es decir, evalúa uno o, a lo más, dos elementos con una operación de comparación. Y tú le estas pasando más de dos.

Algo que se me ocurre, para evitar una especie de redundancia, es

```
#!/bin/bash

main() {

    declare total_argumentos=$#

    [[ $total_argumentos -ne 6 ]] \
        && echo "Cantidad de argumetos incorrecta." \
        && exit 1    

    declare c_palabras_unicas=$(uniq <<< "$( tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$@" | sort )" | wc -l)
    declare mensaje="Repeticiones: $((total_argumentos - c_palabras_unicas))"
    mensaje="${mensaje}\nPalabras diferentes: $c_palabras_unicas"

    [[ $c_palabras_unicas -eq 1 ]] && mensaje="${mensaje}\nTodas las palabras son iguales."
    [[ $c_palabras_unicas -eq $total_argumentos ]] && mensaje="${mensaje}\nTodas las palabras son diferentes."

    printf "$mensaje\n" | column -t -s : 

}

main $@
```

Cuya ejecución daría algo parecido.

```
$ ./script.sh uno uno uno uno uno uno  # Todas los argumentos tiene la cadena "uno".
Repeticiones                      5
Palabras diferentes               1
Todas las palabras son iguales.
$ ./script.sh uno uno uno uno uno dos  # Ahora tienen una cadena "dos".
Repeticiones          4
Palabras diferentes   2
$ ./script.sh uno dos uno dos uno dos  # Se intercalan repetidos.
Repeticiones          4
Palabras diferentes   2
$ ./script.sh {1..6}  # Los numeros del 1 al 6
Repeticiones                         0
Palabras diferentes                  6
Todas las palabras son diferentes.
```

De esta forma, `sort` ordena los argumentos ingresados.

Comment: Esta muy completo , muchas gracias me has ayudado a entender el problema , pero se puede hacer mas sencillo aunque no es tan eficiente ni buena idea. Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada. De casualidad, ¿Sabes por qué tengo un voto negativo? Para modificar o eliminar mi respuesta.

Comment: Ni idea , Ami no me deja puntuar , no tengo 15 de reputación . Yo intenté ponerte uno positivo

Comment: a mi me pareció una muy buena respuesta y por demás completa, tienes un +1